# Calculate the Screen Height on a Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

This drives me crazy.  Lots of times I have carousels and such where I need to reset the screen height with JavaScript responsively.   The issue is that with mobile devices, the screen height includes the little URL window at the top, so the height of the page calculated by "window.innerHeight" or $(window).height(); is off.   Is there a workaround for this?  Happens all the time.

Answer (score 0):

use 'clientWidth' and 'clientHeight' instead

[Determining the dimensions of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements)

Comment: as far as I know these properties are supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the the scaling is effected by viewport or not. Just use plain js to get the value. It will be much easyier to controle:

```js
//Screen
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;
console.log('screen = ',w,' & ',h);
//Screen with ratio
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
var w = screen.width * ratio;
var h = screen.height * ratio;
console.log('screen = ',w,' & ',h);

//Document
  //PS document.width & document.height is no longer supported
var w  = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth //for IE 8 or lower
|| document.body.clientWidth;  //for IE 8 or lower
var h = window.innerHeight
|| document.documentElement.clientHeight  //for IE 8 or lower
|| document.body.clientHeight;  //for IE 8 or lower
console.log('client = ',w,' & ',h);
//Document offset
var w = document.body.offsetWidth
var h = document.body.offsetHeight
console.log('offset = ',w,' & ',h);
//Document fractional offset
var c = document.body.getBoundingClientRect()
console.log(c);
//Scroll
var x = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset;
var y = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset;
console.log('scroll = ',x,' & ',y);
```

Enjoy ;)